# Change length of Countdowntimer

Tags: java, android

I want to change the length of my Countdowntimer when it finishs. So I got a Random Number which changes everytime.

```
standby_time    = 15000
standby_counter = new CountDownTimer(standby_time,1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                ++standby_zaehler;

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                ...
                standby_zaehler = 0;

                rndm_groesse = 60000;
                random_zahl = r.nextInt(rndm_groesse);              
                standby_time = random_zahl;

                standby_counter.start();
            }
        };
```

Where is my fault ? The time is not changing and takes the first value (15sec)

Comment: I dont know android well enough to actually answer this however the problem definitely is because you `standby_time` is a primitive data type and modifying it in the `onFinish` method does not change the value you passed to the `CountDownTimer`. I would look into using the `Timer` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The countdown timers time isnt ment to be changed. You can recreate the timer to alter the time but because you are looking to start it again inside the `onFinish()` method it would be wise to use a different implementation better suited for this task. The `java.util.Timer` class does this well.

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private int standby_zaehler = 0;
private Random r = new Random();

public void scheduleNextTimer() {
    // reset our countdown
    standby_zaehler = 0;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // 1 second passed, remove it to the countdown
            --standby_zaehler;
            // we are finished counting down. get a new max seconds
            if(standby_zaehler < 0) {
                standby_zaehler = r.nextInt(60);
            }
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}
```

As you can see we dont even need to create a new timer, just reset the number and begin again.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful but I dont understand where we start this timer again because were cancelling it but dont start it anywhere. And were reseting our countdown from the beginning and check the standby_zaehler with 0.Then we get a new random number and cancle it.If the timer starts again it is getting the value 0 again , or not ? Sorry If its a stupid question but I really dont get it

Comment: @user3202845 your right! I had originally written something that canceled the timer and started it again but realizing that that was just a waste i removed it. It seems I forgot to remove the `cancel()` method as well. Good catch.